# Boundedness of a singular integral operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, interpolation

My singular integral operator is defined by
\begin{align}
Sf(x)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t-x) \frac{dt}{2\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}t},
\end{align}
that is, a convolution $-\frac{1 }{2\sinh\frac{\pi}2x}\ast f.$ To prove that this is bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1<p<\infty$, I have tried to make use of the following result from Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem:

For $1\le p\le\infty$ there exists a constant $C_p$ such that if $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^1$, then $f\ast g\in L^p$ and
\begin{align*}
||f\ast g||_p\le C_p||g||_1||f||_p.
\end{align*}

This result means it suffices for me to show that $g=-\frac{1 }{2\sinh\frac{\pi}2x}$ is integrable. I have tried to do this as follows:

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $g=-1/(2\sinh\frac{\pi}2x)$, then
\begin{align*}
||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{2\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}x}
&=\left[\frac1{\pi}\ln\left(\tanh\frac{\pi}4x\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
&=\frac1{\pi}\left[\ln\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}2x}-1}{e^{\frac{\pi}2x}+1}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
&=-\frac1{\pi}\ln(-1)\\
&=\text{ diverges}
\end{align*}
that is $g\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and my conclusion is that $S$ is not bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. However, my professor insists that it is bounded. Is there another way of showing that $S$ is indeed bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1<p<\infty$.

$\bf\underline{\text{SO FAR}}.$
I have been able to show that it is strongly bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and it remains to show that it is weakly bounded on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ so that I can use the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem to conclude for $1<p<2$, and then duality to complete the problem. Now, how do I show that it is weakly bounded on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$? Been trying whole day and night and I cannot try any more, please help.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question,  but the first thing that pops out is....is that theorem you quoted an if and only if?  It may be that $$g \notin L^1(\mathbb R)$$ and yet S still be bounded if it wasn't an iff

Comment: The theorem is not an iff, but i trying to figure another way to do it.@Alan

Comment: I would have a closer look at your calculation of $\|g\|_1$ as there are some errors, but it is indeed correct that $\|g\|_1=\infty$. This shows that $S\mathbf1(x)=-\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ where $\mathbf1(x)=1$ for all $x$. This shows $S$ is not even defined on $L^\infty$, let alone bounded.

Comment: Although I guess it probably is not unreasonable to assume $1\le p<\infty$.

Comment: The $1\le p\le\infty$ is just for the theorem, it is for $1<p<\infty$ that I am trying to show boundedness. Sorry for not specifying that.@Jason

Comment: Having a non-integrable kernel (i.e. not in $L^1$) is part of the nature of singular integral operators. The point is that due to cancellation effects one can often still recover $L^p$ bounds. Look up what you learned about Calderón-Zygmund theory.

Comment: Did you try to divide your domain of integration? $1/\sinh(x)$ is  bounded outside $[-1,1]$, and inside it looks like similar to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: Also, note that $\sinh x$ changes sign at $x=0$.